# How do I return the position of 'findNumber' in the 2-dim array 'matrix'?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the position of the number typed by the user (int findNumber).
I realise that I have to return an instance of the type Position, but I'm not sure how to do it. I created an instance in my 'Main' called "numberPosition", but I can't use it in the other class. This is probably very basic stuff but I really can't figure it out.
I'm very new to programming, sorry if the question is worded vaguely. Please go easy on me.

**Main**

```
class Program
{
    Random RNG = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program FindNumber = new Program();
        FindNumber.Start();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        int[,] matrix = new int[8, 10];

        InitMatrixRandom(matrix, 0, 100);
        DisplayMatrix(matrix);

        Console.WriteLine("Give the number to be searched: ");
        int findNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Position numberPosition = new Position();
        numberPosition.FindNumber(matrix, findNumber);

        Console.WriteLine(numberPosition);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    void InitMatrixRandom(int[,] matrix, int min, int max)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                matrix[row, col] = RNG.Next(min, max);
            }
        }
    }

    void DisplayMatrix(int[,] matrix)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0,3} ", matrix[row, col]));
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

**Class**

```
class Position
{
    public Position numberPosition = new Position();

    public Position FindNumber(int[,] matrix, int findNumber)
    {
        int row = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int col = matrix.GetLength(1);

        int y, x;

        for (y = 0; y < col; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < row; x++)
            {
                if (findNumber == matrix[y, x])
                {
                    return numberPosition;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make `FindNumber()` static and return a `new Position(x, y)`?

Comment: The `FindNumber()` function should probably not be a part of the `Position` class. Based on the name of the class, it doesn't make sense (to me) that that should be part of its functionality. Instead, you might want to create a `Matrix` class with.

Comment: Also, doesn't `public Position numberPosition = new Position();` cause infinite recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose of the `Position` is to store an `x,y` position, the `FindNumber()` function does not seem to like it should be part of that class. It could just have to properties to store the `x` and `y`:

```
class Position {
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public Position(int x, int y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return X + "," + Y;
    }
}
```

You could also create a matrix class to manage all of that functionality

```
class Matrix
{
    int[,] matrix;
    Random RNG = new Random();

    public Matrix(int rows, int columns)
    {
        matrix = new int[rows, columns];
    }

    void InitMatrixRandom(int min, int max)
    {
        // Same as before....
    }

    void DisplayMatrix()
    {
        // Same as before....
    }
    void DisplayMatrix(Position numberToHilite)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                if (numberToHilite.X == col && numberToHilite.Y == row) {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                }
                else {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                }
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0,3} ", matrix[row, col]));
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    public Position FindNumber(int findNumber)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < matrix.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < matrix.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                if (findNumber == matrix[y, x])
                {
                    // Return a Position object
                    return new Position(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option is what I was looking for. Didn't realise I had to use the constructor to define its type. I'd like to reprint the matrix after finding the number and then I want only that number to have the colour Red in the matrix. How do you think I can accomplish this?

Comment: @LeroydeSmet To change colors in the console see: [Console.ForegroundColor Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.foregroundcolor?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I managed to get that far, but how do I apply it to specifically one element in the 2-dimensional array? (leaving the other elements (random numbers) at their default colours).

Comment: @LeroydeSmet You could create a 2nd function to display with hi-lite. I have updated my answer with an example. After finding the number, pass the found `Position` to the new function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign value to the Position

```
class Position
{

    public int PositionX {get;set;}
    public int PositionY {get;set;}

    public Position FindNumber(int[,] matrix, int findNumber)
    {
        int row = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int col = matrix.GetLength(1);

        int y, x;

        for (y = 0; y < col; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < row; x++)
            {
                if (findNumber == matrix[y, x])
                {
                    return new Position { PositionX = x, PositionY = y };
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```